# Using Ubuntu with a dial-up connection

Tags: internet, serial-port, wvdial

Is it possible to install Ubuntu on a machine with *only* a dial-up connection?  That is, does the Ubuntu install CD come with *everything* needed to set up an Internet connection using a dial-up modem (I have a USRobotics Courier V.Everything connected to a RS232 port on a Lava Quattro-PCI).

I presently run CentOS (5.9), which does include support for dialup Internet access out-of-the-box (*all* of the modules for dialup are on the distro DVD).  When I ran the UBuntu CD (12.04.1 desktop), there was no sign of dial-up Internet support.  Am I faced with a chicken or egg problem?

Comment: Very old school. After making an answer I found this just now: http://goodbyemicrosoft.net/news.php?item.697.4 so the answer probably is NO. You will need to download the required packages from another machine prior to installation.

Comment: Also interesting: http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu:Raring#Modems_.2F_Dial-up  "These instructions require gnome-network-admin (install while connected to a **wired ethernet connection**): "

Comment: It might be old school, but dial up internet access is actually very common in *rural USA*.  The United States is (at this point) very "backward" when it comes to Internet availablity.  There is broadband in the cities and suburbia, but out in the country side it is hard to come by.  And no, for many areas wireless internet (including Cell and Satelite based) is not allways a workable solution either -- wireless has big problems with mountains and trees!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu keeps one CD distribution, not a sFedora, debian or CentOs, where you can download complete x CD distribution (where x>1). But you can try live distribution, try to set dial up connection according to this guide (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DialupModemHowto) and/or download packages from here (http://packages.ubuntu.com/).

Comment: OK, the https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DialupModemHowto page helped.  Some notes:  the first GUI option is not available with 12.04.  The command line option using pppconfig does work.  I guess when it comes to 'user friendly dialup configuration' Ubuntu pretty much sucks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, wvdial is on the distro/live CD, so it can be installed (not super easy or anything). Setting up PPP is something of a bear.  Hell, it was *easier* back in the days of Slackware 3.0 (Kernel 0.99!) to set up dialup internet!

I guess in the Ubuntu world, nobody uses dialup?

(In case you are wondering, no I am not in some remote "third world" contry, I am in the USA, in Western Mass.)

Fornunately, I have a working CentOS 5.9 system I can copy files from and am something of a Linux Admin expert (with RedHat distros, not Debian/Ubuntu).